# Iterating over directory with specified path in Bash

Tags: regex, bash, file, loops, directory

```
pathToBins=$1

bins="${pathToBins}contigs.fa.metabat-bins-*"

for fileName in $bins
do
    echo $fileName

done
```

My goal is to attach a path to my file name. I can iterate over a folder and get the file name when I don't attach the path. My challenge is when I add the path echo fileName my regular expression no longer works and I get "/home/erikrasmussen/Desktop/Script/realLargeMetaBatBinscontigs.fa.metabat-bins-*" where the regular expression '*' is treated like a string. How can I get the path and also the full file name while iterating over a folder of files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I don't really know how your files are arranged on your hard drive, a casual glance at `"/home/erikrasmussen/Desktop/Script/realLargeMetaBatBinscontigs.fa.metabat-bins-*"` suggests that it is missing a <kbd>/</kbd> before `contigs`. If that is the case, then you should change your definition of bins to:

```
bins="${pathToBins}/contigs.fa.metabat-bins-*"
```

However, it is much more robust to use bash arrays instead of relying on filenames to not include whitespace and metacharacters. So I would suggest:

```
bins=(${pathToBins}/contigs.fa.metabat-bins-*)
for fileName in "${bins[@]}"
do
    echo "$fileName"
done
```

Bash normally does not expand a pattern which doesn't match any file, so in that case you will see the original pattern. If you use the array formulation above, you could set the bash option `nullglob`, which will cause the unmatched pattern to vanish instead, leaving an empty array.

Comment: Any advantage to the array notation over: `for fileName in "${pathToBins}"/contigs.fa.metabat-bins-*; do echo "$fileName"; done`?  If the array is needed later, then saving it once is better, but where the info is used once, there's no particular need to save it in the array.  (I agree that arrays should be used more often than they are, though.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I agree, if `bins` isn't going to be reused, there is no point in creating it. I was just trying to maintain a parallel with the OP, in which `bins` is deliberately created, but as a string rather than as an array. I (perhaps erroneously) assumed that the question is a snippet and that `bins` will be used more than once in the final script.